# LocalDB and Visual Studio MDF files version

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, localdb

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to generate `.MDF` files in a specific LocalDB version? If I go to `Add New Item > Data > Service-based Database` it creates a `.MDF` file with v13 (2016).

I need to create it in v12 (2014) and keep using it in that version without Visual Studio telling me to update to a newer version.

Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to install SQL Server 2014 LocalDB and then use that instance to create your new `.mdf` file

Comment: I installed VS 2015 years ago and it installed LocalDB 2014 and now with update 3 it installed LocalDB 2016.

I have the two of them but it uses the 2016 one (LocalDB V13).

I don't know what to do.